# Java local vs instance variable access speed

Tags: java, performance, variables, optimization

So my question is about variable accessing speed in Java. Today in my "CS" (if you can call it that) the teacher presented a similar example to the following of a List:

```
public class ListExample<T> {
    private Node<T> head;
    private Node<T> tail;

    private class Node<T> { /* ... */ }

    public void append(T content) {
        if (!isEmpty()) {
            Node<T> dummy = new Node<T>(content);
            head = dummy;
            tail = dummy;

            head.setNext(head);
            // or this
            dummy.setNext(dummy);

        } else { /* ... */ }
    }

    // more methods
    // ...
}
```

My question is: Would the call to `head.setNext(head)` be slower than `dummy.setNext(dummy)` ? Even if it's not noticeable.
I was wondering this since `head` is obviously and instance var of the class and dummy is local, so would the local access be faster?

Comment: Since `dummy` would be on the heap along with `head` I would say their access time is the same. You are still having to access the heap in both scenarios.

Comment: How could you say that X is slower than Y if the difference is "not noticeable" (implying not measurable)? Regardless, when in doubt: [**measure it.**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103/139010)

Comment: For they are pointing to the same object, I;d say that there will be no difference

Comment: [Premature optimization is the root of all evil.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4bQOSRm9YiQ)

Comment: @MattBall with that I really meant if there was any difference in the number of instructions that would need to be executed to get the value of either `head` or `dummy` (not JVM instructions since those will obvoiusly differ [`aload` and something])

Comment: For head it will have to dereference the `this` pointer but for dummy it takes the value off the stack.

Comment: In the interpreter the fastest access is to a local, next is an instance variable, slowest is a static.  With the JITC, however, that can dance around a bit.

Comment: @C.B. - "dummy" would be on the JVM stack, not in the heap.  DrYap has it right.

Comment: @HotLicks in regards to the objects or their references?

Comment: @C.B. - Objects are never stored in an instance variable or a local variable, only references are stored there.

Comment: @HotLicks i will be removing these comments as they detract from the question, but I was saying once you have the references for each you must access the heap. I thought retrieving the reference for `head` would be negligible

Comment: @C.B. - Yeah, this is arguing over angels on a pinhead.  In a well-designed JVM neither is expensive enough to worry about (though in some early JVMs there was cause for worry).

Comment: @C.B. - But it should be noted that the same discussion applies to accessing a scalar value rather than a reference.

Comment: I don't see how this question is "opinion-based".  I lead the development of the Java implementation for IBM iSeries.  My answer and comments here are based on facts.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Ok, I've written a micro-benchmark (as suggested by @Joni & @MattBall) and here are the results for 1 x 1000000000 accesses for each a local and an instance variable:

```
Average time for instance variable access: 5.08E-4
Average time for local variable access: 4.96E-4
```

For 10 x 1000000000 accesses each:

```
Average time for instance variable access:4.723E-4
Average time for local variable access:4.631E-4
```

For 100 x 1000000000 accesses each:

```
Average time for instance variable access: 5.050300000000002E-4
Average time for local variable access: 5.002400000000001E-4
```

**So it seems that local variable accesses are indeed faster that instance var accesses** (even if both point to the same object).

Note: I didn't want to find this out, because of something I wanted to optimize, it was just pure interest.

P.S. Here is the code for the micro-benchmark:

```
public class AccessBenchmark {
    private final long N = 1000000000;
    private static final int M = 1;

    private LocalClass instanceVar;

    private class LocalClass {
        public void someFunc() {}
    }

    public double testInstanceVar() {
        // System.out.println("Running instance variable benchmark:");
        instanceVar = new LocalClass();

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            instanceVar.someFunc();
        }

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        double avg = (elapsed * 1000.0) / N;

        // System.out.println("elapsed time = " + elapsed + "ms");
        // System.out.println(avg + " microseconds per execution");

        return avg;
    }

    public double testLocalVar() {
        // System.out.println("Running local variable benchmark:");
        instanceVar = new LocalClass();
        LocalClass localVar = instanceVar;

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < N; i++) {
            localVar.someFunc();
        }

        long elapsed = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

        double avg = (elapsed * 1000.0) / N;

        // System.out.println("elapsed time = " + elapsed + "ms");
        // System.out.println(avg + " microseconds per execution");

        return avg;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AccessBenchmark bench;

        double[] avgInstance = new double[M];
        double[] avgLocal = new double[M];

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
            bench = new AccessBenchmark();

            avgInstance[i] = bench.testInstanceVar();
            avgLocal[i] = bench.testLocalVar();

            System.gc();
        }

        double sumInstance = 0.0;
        for (double d : avgInstance) sumInstance += d;
        System.out.println("Average time for instance variable access: " + sumInstance / M);

        double sumLocal = 0.0;
        for (double d : avgLocal) sumLocal += d;
        System.out.println("Average time for local variable access: " + sumLocal / M);
    }
}
```

Comment: It should be noted that, with differences this small, "trivial" things like cache alignment could throw off the results.

Comment: @HotLicks: Sure, but this is something a benchmark frameworks should already handle (caliper allocates some random-length garbage) before measurements because of this, so I'd hope JMH does it too). In general, I rather agree, any tiny change can throw it off, I'm just surprised how consistent the results are.

Comment: I am surprised that the results are so consistent.  I'm not surprised at the results -- they're about what I'd expect, given that the vast majority of the time is spent in the instance method call/return vs the variable reference.

Comment: @Joseph: I think you draw totally wrong conclusion from those number. What the numbers actually indicate is this: **There is no significant difference in performance between the two alternatives.** The difference between your measurements is so tiny that it is well inside the margin of error of any benchmark.

Answer (score 16):

In general, an access to an instance variable (of the `this` object) requires an `aload_0` (to load `this` to the top of the stack) followed by `getfield`.  Referencing a local variable requires only the `aload_n` to pull the value out of its assigned location in the stack.

Further, `getfield` must reference the class definition to determine where in the class (what offset) the value is stored.  This could be several additional hardware instructions.

Even with a JITC it's unlikely that the local reference (which would normally be zero/one hardware operation) would ever be slower than the instance field reference (which would have to be at least one operation, maybe 2-3).

(Not that this matters all that much -- the speed of both is quite good, and the difference could only become significant in very bizarre circumstances.)

Answer (score 10):

Like in the comments, I don't think there's difference in the time taken. I think what you might be referring to is better exemplified in Java SE codebase. For example, in `java.lang.String`:

```
public void getBytes(int srcBegin, int srcEnd, byte dst[], int dstBegin) {
    //some code you can check out

    char[] val = value;
    while (i < n) {
        dst[j++] = (byte)val[i++];    /* avoid getfield opcode */
    }
}
```

In the above code, `value` is an *instance* variable and since there was a `while` *loop*  where individual elements of `value` were going to be accessed, they brought it from the heap to the stack (*local variable*) thus optimizing.

You can also check out knowledge shared by Jon Skeet, Vivin and few others [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4761681/avoiding-getfield-opcode).

Comment: This is an interesting point, it suggest that there is in fact a difference. Though this String code may be old and there might be some optimizations that the JIT compiler does not that it didn't at the time of writing.

Comment: When setting a local just for this optimization, I wonder how many accesses makes it worthwhile (unlike the OP, who already had the local).

Answer (score 4):

From a micro architecture perspective, reading a local variable may be cheaper because it's likely in a register or at least in the CPU cache. In general reading an instance variable may cause an expensive cache miss. In this case though the variable was just written, so it will likely be in the cache anyway. You could write a micro benchmark to find if there's any difference.

Comment: It's clear that a local variable will give you better cache coherence, but how about comparing local instance access vs static access?  Would static fields and methods run a greater or lesser chance to not be in cache at any given moment?

Answer (score -1):

I think using `dummy` might be at the *very* most, 1 cycle faster, assuming it was left in a register, but it depends on the specific CPU architecture, and what `setNext` looks like, and the JVM you're using, and it's really unpredictable how the code might look once in its final [JIT'd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) form. The JVM could potentially see that head == dummy, and if so, the executed code for both cases would be identical. This is much, much too tiny a case to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

I can assure you that whatever performance gains one might gain from this will be offset by the headache of looking at confusingly written code. Let the compiler figure this out. I will concede that all things being equal, the local variable is probably slightly faster, if only because there are fewer bytecode instructions involved. However, who is to say that future versions of the JVM won't change this?

In short, write code that is easy to read first. If, after that, you have a performance concern, profile.

Answer (score -2):

When in doubt look at the byte code generated

```
public void append(java.lang.Object);
 Code:
  0:    new #2; //class ListExample$Node
  3:    dup
  4:    aload_0
  5:    aload_1
  6:    invokespecial   #3; //Method ListExample$Node."<init>":(LListExample;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
  9:    astore_2
  10:   aload_0
  11:   aload_2
  12:   putfield    #4; //Field head:LListExample$Node;
  15:   aload_0
  16:   aload_2
  17:   putfield    #5; //Field tail:LListExample$Node;
  20:   aload_0
  21:   getfield    #4; //Field head:LListExample$Node;
  24:   aload_0
  25:   getfield    #4; //Field head:LListExample$Node;
  28:   invokevirtual   #6; //Method ListExample$Node.setNext:(LListExample$Node;)V
  31:   aload_2
  32:   aload_2
  33:   invokevirtual   #6; //Method ListExample$Node.setNext:(LListExample$Node;)V
  36:   return

}
```

Either you get aload followed by getfield or 2 x aload. Seems to me they would be identical..

Comment: Thanks for your answer, have you got any idea why you would need 2x `aload_2`? Shouldn't 1 be enough to get the ref to `dummy` ?

Comment: @JosephAdams The compiler does almost no optimisation. All the optimisation is done by the JIT at runtime so the actual native code generated might look completely different.

Comment: This tells you absolutely nothing about the runtime speed.

Comment: Just because they're the same number of bytecodes you think they would be the same speed??

Comment: @HotLicks No, but generally if there are less bytecodes (and they do [about] the same thing) I'd say it's more probable that it runs faster.

Comment: @JosephAdams: I guess, there's some correlation, but you can never be sure. [Recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21567248/strange-performance-drop-of-jdk8-localdate-toepochday), I wondered how it comes that an algorithm using a couple of division can be relatively fast, but now I see there are no division after JIT.