# Why is a (final) local variable declared when using an instance variable in Java?

Tags: java, oop, final, instance-variables, local-variables

Consider this code I found from the LinkedList class in the JDK.

```
public E getLast() {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    if (l == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return l.item;
}
```

**First question:** Why is this seemingly redundant local variable `l` declared in this code? From what I see, we could've simply used `last` instead.

---

In the next code from the HashMap class, the same thing is done. The local variable `tab` is declared to be to equal to the instance variable `table`.

**Second question:** Why is `final` not used here with `tab` like it was used in the previous code?

```
final Node<K,V> getNode(int hash, Object key) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
    if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 &&
        (first = tab[(n - 1) & hash]) != null) {
        if (first.hash == hash && // always check first node
            ((k = first.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
            return first;
        if ((e = first.next) != null) {
            if (first instanceof TreeNode)
                return ((TreeNode<K,V>)first).getTreeNode(hash, key);
            do {
                if (e.hash == hash &&
                    ((k = e.key) == key || (key != null && key.equals(k))))
                    return e;
            } while ((e = e.next) != null);
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I assume it's for thread safety, so no write occurs between null check and return. There are assignments in the of clauses of the map code too.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. But why was `tab` not declared `final` then?

Comment: Please don't ask multiple questions in one ... question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **First question:** Why is this seemingly redundant local variable `l` declared in this code? From what I see, we could've simply used `last` instead.

I can think of two likely reasons:

- Although LinkedList is not intended to be threadsafe, it's still preferable for it to behave consistently when that doesn't conflict with any more important goals (such as performance). If 'getLast()' referred twice to 'last', it would be possible for 'last' to be null the second time, triggering a NullPointerException instead of the desired NoSuchElementException.

  - This accords with LinkedList's support for ConcurrentModificationException — a best-effort attempt to detect bugs, but no actual threadsafety guarantees.
- Performance:

  - A local variable access may be slightly faster: [Java local vs instance variable access speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21613098/java-local-vs-instance-variable-access-speed)
  - Using a local variable may make it clearer to the optimizer that it can store this reference in a register and reuse it, without having to re-check the value of 'last'. (Technically the Java Memory Model would already let it do this, but it's possible that not all versions of the JVM are smart enough to do so, or perhaps even some versions *intentionally* don't, for whatever reason.)

  JDK classes take performance very seriously, because they're incredibly widely used, and because they're "close friends" with the JVM.

In either case, please be aware that JDK code doesn't really reflect Java best practices for mainstream code; it's interesting to think about these decisions, but please don't be tempted to emulate them!

> **Second question:** Why is `final` not used here with `tab` like it was used in the previous code?

I doubt there's a particular reason here; there would be no downsides to using `final`.

Answer (score 4):

The major reason to code like this is thread safety. Take the first example:

```
public E getLast() {
    final Node<E> l = last;
    if (l == null)
        throw new NoSuchElementException();
    return l.item;
}
```

If we simply removed the local variable `l` and accessed `last` directly then a different thread to change `last` to be null between us checking for `null` and trying to access `l.item`, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.

The way it's written right here (and assuming that `l.item` doesn't get overwritten in some cases) this method will always *either* throw a `NoSuchElementException` or return a value that is (or at least was at some point) part of the list.

The choice to declare a local variable as `final` is almost entirely up to style choices, as it only affects what code the compiler will accept and not influence the actual code generation. A `final` local variable and an effectively-final one (i.e. one that gets assigned once and never changed after that) don't behave differently in any way.